# get text from dynamic table cell to to database

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, jsp, servlets

Alright so what I want to do is save text from my table to the database.  The table is dynamically generated via a hibernate connection to the db.  A sample of the html in the .jsp for the table:

```
display:column property="ticketId" href="/ossWeb/displayTicketEdit.do" paramId="ticketId" title="Ticket ID"/>
<display:column property="ATCNotes" title="ATC Notes" class="notes" />
<display:column property="issue" title="Issue"/>
<display:column property="status" title="Status"/>
```

Each property maps directly to a column of a view in the db.
I use this jQuery to allow any cell in the ATC Notes column to be clicked and turn into a text box:

```
$(".notes").live('click',(
function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text('');
    $('<input type="text" />').appendTo($(this)).val(text).select().blur(
        function(){
            var newText = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(newText).find('input:text').remove();
       });
}));
```

When you click off the cell, the text replaces what was already in the cell.  Each row corresponds to a ticketId as can be seen in my first line of the jsp.  Now my question is, how do I get that entered text to the db? I have a check box on each row, and for that, I can just assign it a value of "${ATCQueue.ticketId}" but there doesn't seem to be any similar way to differentiate each cell in the ATC Notes column.
I've heard of AJAX being used for something somewhat close to this, but honestly I'm pretty new to this and know next to nothing about AJAX.

Comment: You want an update to your db each time the content of a cell changes ?

Comment: No I have a submit button on the page that's submitting other changes successfully.  I want all of the changes to the page to be committed then.

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework ? Some frameworks like Struts simplify this kind of things.

Comment: Yeah struts. How can that help? New graduate here, so I'm floating in a sea of stuff I know very little about.

Comment: Well in Struts you have Actions right ? If you have an attribute "att" in your action, and a field name="att" in your form, submitting your form to the action will automatically set your attribute "att" to the value in your form. I recommended you read a bit more on Struts, you should find out how to post values using Actions.

Comment: So on my page right now, I have a drop down box with employee names.  Then in this table, there is a checkbox and ticketid on each row. The checkbox is given the value of the ticket id by saying value="${ATCQueue.ticketId}" (ATCQueue being the name of table).  When submit is clicked, the values of the textboxes that are checked are passed to the servlet, which then calls other java files with sql written to change the database to assign that employee those tickets (which all works fine).  So if I'm correct, I'm already using actions, or perhaps I'm misunderstand.

Comment: I'm going to try pulling both ticketid and atcnotes column and matching them before passing them on and see how that goes. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you mandatorily need AJAX for this. You can write an action servlet and submit the form.

Or you can go for native AJAX using XMLHttpRequest/Response. Another way would be to use DWR framework.

Comment: so then on my servlet then, what can I do? I do something like 
`'String ATCNotes[]=request.getParameter("ATCNotes")'`?
And then if that works, how do I associate each entry in the array with the corresponding ticket value in the table?

Comment: FYI I already have a servlet that is taking changes and committing them to the db fine.  I just don't know how to deal with this specific change.

Comment: Add paramId attribute to your display:column tag. paramId = "ATCNotes" Then you should be able to get it using request.getParameter("ATCNotes")

Comment: Alright well then how do I associate it with the ticket id that is on the same row? Unlike a text box, I can't just assign each cell a hidden value right?

Comment: Ahh wait, so perhaps I can just grab both the ticketid column and the notes column since I imagine they'll have a 1:1 association.  I'll give that a try then and see how things turn out.

Comment: Although the initial answer isn't really what I was looking for, I'll give you the check for now since the comments helped.  I'll come back with any questions/feedback. Thanks!!

Comment: Alright so here's what I'm doing.  My code for the checkboxes on each row are:
`<display:column title = "Assign">
  <input type="checkbox" name="assignATC" value="${ATCQueue.ticketId}" />
 </display:column>`
And then in the submit servlet is:
`String checkedATCStr[]=request.getParameterValues("assignATC");`
So I end up with a string array of the value parameter for each checkbox.  When I try the same thing with the notes column
`String ATCNotesStr[]=request.getParameterValues("ATCNotes");` I am getting an empty array even though one of the rows does have a value

Comment: did you add name/paramId to this tag?... <display:column property="ATCNotes" title="ATC Notes" class="notes" />

Comment: It now reads `<display:column property="ATCNotes" title="ATC Notes" class="notes" paramId="ATCNotes"/>` so, yes it does indeed.  You can't use the name attribute in a display:column I don't believe so that's out.

Comment: I think I am missing something... your assignATC has an input tag, but ATCNotes doesn't?

Comment: The problem is this from what I've been reading.  There's no way for the submit action to 'read' what is in between the td tags.  If I could somehow have the paramId be set as the text that is entered between the td tags, then I could do it that way.  What potentially might work is some kind of hidden field with a unique value created and inserted each time the user edits the text. I'll need to look into it further.  I'm going to remove the 'solved check' for now just so people won't disregard looking because its solved.  I'll give it back later though.

Comment: No ATCNotes does not have an input tag.  Check the code at the very top to see. I use jQuery to create a textbox and then destroy when they click away from it as you can see from the above code.  Perhaps I need to add something to the jQuery.

Comment: may be instead of destroying the textbox, you can change it to type hidden.. that way your getParameterValues() will find a name to refer to

Comment: Well if you just change it to type hidden, it would hide all the text that was just typed inside it.  I definitely don't want to do that.  I'm messing around with it a little again today, so I'll let you know. probably adding a second input that is hidden will work.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.First thing if you want to save bulk amount of data I i.e; multiple row and multiple column then you need to set a flag(a hidden field or
>   local storage in html 5) for modified rows.
>   2.Iterate through th rows of the table and generate xml or json .
>   3.yes you heard it right the Ajax, now send the data to your code behind through Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but you're going to have to go in much more depth than that.  More specifically, example code of what you speak of.  I'm new to almost all of this and have done a good bit of looking into it but still a bit lost.